# Need to convert the below awk command into sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

I need to convert the below awk command into sed, 
`awk -F ',' '$2 ~ /^ *[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" *$/{sub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}'`

Below is my input file:

sample.txt:

`3",3"`
`6-position,6-position`
`7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2",7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2"`
`4.8",4.8"`
`Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148,Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148`

And i need the output as below,

output.txt:

`3",3`
`6-position,`
`7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2",`
`4.8",4.8`
`Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148,`
So basically I need to print the numeric value for the " symbol, other non-numeric text needs to be replaced by a empty line, the problem with awk command is the 2,3 and 5 line is getting removed.

Comment: really nice, you have `-F ','`, and also `$2` all over your awk codes. but I cannot find any comma in your input file. did you copy the wrong awk line?

Comment: You have perfectly working `sed` solutions as answers to your earlier question which was exactly the same ...

Comment: No @AdrianFrühwirth, that Sed command is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I commented, the awk one-liner doesn't make sense for your input file. However you could try this sed line:

```
sed -r '/^[0-9.]+"$/{s/"$//;n;};s/.*//' file
```

this works for your input file.

```
kent$  cat file
3"
6-position
7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2"
4.8"
Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148    
kent$  sed -r '/^[0-9.]+"$/{s/"$//;n;};s/.*//' file
3


4.8
(here, the last line is empty too.)
```

**EDIT**

remove `-r` option, and adjust the sed to work with new input/output:

```
sed  's/^\([^,]*,\)\([0-9.]*\)".*$/\1\2/;t;s/^\([^,]*,\).*/\1/' file
```

This line worked with your new input example:

```
kent$  cat file
3",3"
6-position,6-position
7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2",7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2"
4.8",4.8"
Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148,Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148

kent$  sed  's/^\([^,]*,\)\([0-9.]*\)".*$/\1\2/;t;s/^\([^,]*,\).*/\1/' file
3",3
6-position,
7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2",
4.8",4.8
Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148,
```

Comment: Hi @Kent i missed to add that in input file. but i want the sed to be performed on column 2, and my unix version is not accepting sed -r

Comment: @GanzRicanz see EDIT, it should work with your example.

Comment: i getting only empty file.

Comment: you never mentioned which sed do you have, just say "doesn't work". the sed line is there. and I copied my screen when I executed that line with your input file. it worked with my gnu sed (without -r). If you have other sed implementation, it is fine. you could read my sed line, and adjust it to fit your sed. You have seen my idea by reading my codes, you have read my code, haven't you? I don't think I can help you further. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)*\)"$/\1/g' \
-e '/^\([0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)*\)$/! s/^.*$//g' sample.txt
```

Comment: hi @Ravoori, how to use this command for particular colum?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with both, awk and sed.
Since I have no Linux (shell) on my phone I'll try to help out with a sed solution:

```
sed -e 's/^([0-9.]+)"$|.*/\1/g' < file
```

Should do the job