# what's wrong in the below awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

`awk -F ',' '$2 ~ /^ *[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" *$/{sub(/"/, "\n", $2);}' sample.txt > out.txt`

hi all,

what's wrong in the above awk command, i'm getting only the empty file.
Realted to [Need to convert the below awk command into sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502238/need-to-convert-the-below-awk-command-into-sed)

sample.txt:

`3",3"`
`6-position,6-position`
`7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2",7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2"`
`4.8",4.8"`
`Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148,Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148`

expected output is,

output.txt:

`3",3`
`6-position,`
`7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2",`
`4.8",4.8`
`Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148,`

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing what's in your input file.

Comment: Please post sample input and expected output from the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what's wrong in the below awk
>
> awk -F ',' '$1 ~ /^ *[0-9]*(.[0-9]+)?" *$/{sub(/"/, "\n", $1);}'
>   sample.txt > out.txt

just answer your question directly:

Assume the regex part is correct. you did the substitution, but didn't print/output anything. so you will get an empty `out.txt`.

**EDIT**

add a working awk solution base on your example:

```
kent$  awk -F, -v OFS="," '{if($2~/^[0-9.]+"$/)sub(/"/,"",$2);else $2=""}1' file
3",3
6-position,
7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2",
4.8",4.8
Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148,
```

Comment: Hi @kent i used below command `awk -F ',' '$2 ~ /^ *[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" *$/{sub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}' sample.txt > out.txt` .
only second column alone getting printed i want to get the result as  expected output mentioned in the summary
how p

Comment: my answer is to your question. I pointed out why you got an empty file. the awk line in your comment is a completely different one. $1 $2? btw, you have posted 3 questions, they are very similar/same. also you have got many answers, none of them helps?

Comment: $1 $2 will work this scenario, how about a file contains 50+ columns?
i'm stuck here.

Comment: @GanzRicanz I added a working awk solution. hope your problem gets solved.

Comment: have you ever mentioned this requirement in your question? anyway, try my awk line.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks a ton @kent, i know using if else will solve my problem. but don't knowhow to use that in awk, your cmd works like a charm. just modified bit for my requierment.. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data there's nothing "wrong" with your awk statement as such, it's just that your regex doesn't match a single of your input.